# Typescript Class - private and protected properties are visible

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript 3.4.5 and I have declared a class *Person* like following and created its instance *person*:

```
class Person {
    name: string;
    private personType: string = "Awesome Guy";
    protected age: number = 27;

    constructor(name: string, public userName: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

const person = new Person("John", "john");
console.log(person); // {"userName":"john","personType":"Awesome Guy","age":27,"name":"John"}
```

But, when I printed the value of *person* object, it displayed values of **private** and **protected** members also. I can even access them like *person.personType* and *person.age* (though compiler gives error), it prints correct values and not **undefined**. What's wrong with this? Please help to clarify the doubt.

Comment: Typescript compiles to Javascript which doesn't have such a notion as private and protected properties. The annotations are for compile-time errors, not for runtime safety.

Comment: FYI this will probably change when JS classes support private with `#` syntax, but that will probably not impact existing `private` field declarations

Comment: But, when I don't initialize private and protected properties, they don't show up in object, not even as `undefined`. That seems little weird.

Comment: Js private field proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields and TS impact: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31670

Comment: @GeniusGo that is a different issue, uninitialized fields never show up because JS has no clue the field exists until you initialize it

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, I'm little new to TypeScript, so sorry to ask, but do these **private** and **protected** access modifiers have real life use, if it doesn't encapsulates at runtime?

Comment: @GeniusGo sure they do, the whole point of typescript is compile time checks. Much like a type does not have any run time error if violated but is still useful  because of compile time checks

Comment: Thanks, @TitianCernicova-Dragomir for clearing the doubt.